# How to prevent the shopping cart from appearing every time you add an item to the cart?

Tags: snipcart

Per the [3.x documentation](https://docs.snipcart.com/v3/setup/installation), adding `data-config-add-product-behavior="none"` to the `div#snipcart` element is not working for me, the cart still appears every time I add an item to the cart.

At a lost for what to do, everything else is working fine for me...

Comment: Thanks for the hint with the param - I did not know that. Ad your problem: here it is working. Do you get an error message in the browser console?